# WSO2 MI 4.1.0 SFTP protocol: How to construct URI from Environment variables

Tags: wso2, sftp, esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, mi

In my scenario, I download files from FTP. My transport.vfs.FileURI look like `vfs:sftp://login:password@ip/`. Is it possible to set the login and password by dynamically retrieving the value from an environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass the entire URL like below. AFAIK you cannot concat multiple variables and construct the URL within the Parameter.

```
<parameter name="ransport.vfs.FileURI">$SYSTEM:SFTP_ENV_NAME</parameter>
```

You can also use the securevalt for this.

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">vfs:sftp://{wso2:vault-decrypt('encryptedValue')}</parameter>
```